# __ in php, what does it do?

Tags: php, prestashop

I'm trying to add tinymce to the category block in Prestashop. (1.4.7.3)
I found following snippet which should do the trick, but I get some errors.

```
<?php

class Category extends CategoryCore
{
    public function getTranslationsFieldsChild() {
        self::validateFieldsLang();

        $fieldsArray = array('name', 'link_rewrite', 'meta_title', 'meta_keywords', 'meta_description');
        $fields = array();
        $languages = Language::getLanguages();
        $defaultLanguage = Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT');
        foreach ($languages as $language)
        {
            $fields[$language['id_lang']]['id_lang'] = $language['id_lang'];
            $fields[$language['id_lang']][$this->identifier] = intval($this->id);
            $fields[$language['id_lang']]['description'] = (isset($this->description[$language['id_lang']])) ? Tools::htmlentitiesDecodeUTF8(pSQL($this->description[$language['id_lang']], true)) : '';
            foreach ($fieldsArray as $field)
            {
                if (!Validate::isTableOrIdentifier($field))
                    die(Tools::displayError());

                __regexoperators___ /*Check fields validity */
                if (isset($this->{$field}[$language['id_lang']]) AND !empty($this->{$field}[$language['id_lang']]))
                    $fields[$language['id_lang']][$field] = pSQL($this->{$field}[$language['id_lang']]);
                elseif (in_array($field, $this->fieldsRequiredLang))
                    $fields[$language['id_lang']][$field] = pSQL($this->{$field}[$defaultLanguage]);
                else
                    $fields[$language['id_lang']][$field] = '';
            }
        }
        return $fields;
    }
}
```

I was wondering what the

```
__regexoperators___
```

does exactly.

Is it possible that my version of php doesn't know what to do with the "__ "?

Could I replace the "__" with a function call?

thanks in advance

Comment: It's very possible yes. My PHP also doesn't recognise it. Have you tried removing it?

Comment: If I comment out the first and last line in the script, I no longer get the error. But it doesn't show the rte either...

Comment: Wait, you just completely changed the provided code. wth

Comment: So do you have an idea why I get the 'unexpected global' error on the next line. Does it have something to do with the __regexoperators or with the global itself?

Comment: I've edited the code to make it hold the entire snippet. But comments are comming in to fast...

Comment: In your last edit you have `__regexoperators___` commented out. Is it supposed to be?

Comment: See [this post](http://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/174037-solved-how-to-add-tinymce-wysiwyg-to-categories-description-text-field/). Notice that `__regexoperators___` is not present anywhere. It also looks like there are a number of changes required to get this to work, not just one small snippet.

Comment: sorry, it shouldn't be commented out.

Comment: Where did you find this snippet?

Comment: http://www.jellygnite.com.au/blog/index.php/archive/update-display-html-in-prestashop-category-description-v-1-4/ for snippet. Off course I did all the steps, but I get the error in nr. 5, than when I comment those lines out I get the error on nr. 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't do anything in this case. It's just a byproduct of using the [jQuery Litelighter](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Litelighter) plugin to highlight snippets of code on the [blog post](http://www.jellygnite.com.au/blog/index.php/archive/update-display-html-in-prestashop-category-description-v-1-4/) you've copy/pasted that code from.

If you're going to search the same code snippet in the HTML source, i.e. without syntax highlighting, you'll see that `__regexoperators___` doesn't appear there.

Taking a look at the [jQuery Litelighter plugin source code](https://github.com/trentrichardson/jQuery-Litelighter/blob/master/jquery-litelighter.js) will also show that they're using underscore separated markers for their parsing.